# Set same IP address for two docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm spinning two docker containers from a docker-compose file. One container is running with service and another container is running to execute tests for the service. 
My docker-compose looks like below:

```
version: "3"

services:
  service-1:
    build: <service_path>
    image: <service_image>
    container_name: service-container-1
    networks:
      docker_net_3:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.8.2
  test-executor-1:
    build: <test_scripts_path>
    image: <test_scripts_image>
    container_name: test-container-1
    networks:
      docker_net_3:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.8.1
networks:
  docker_net_3:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.8.0/24
```

I want to run the same setup on the same machine with the same IP address for the containers with a different network. 
So that my tests can access the service URLs as I specified in the test executor config.

I tried to create a different docker network with the same subnet but it fails with the below error.

```
Creating network "test_executor_docker_net_3" with driver "bridge"
ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
```

How can I set the same IP address to multiple containers?

Comment: This should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300613/multiple-docker-compose-container-single-ip

Answer (score 3):

You should do two things here:

1. Within the some Docker Compose file you can use the names of services as hostnames.  This is because [Docker Compose creates a Docker-internal network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and Docker provides an internal DNS service.
2. Hostnames of services you're trying to connect to really should be configurable.  In your example, your test environment is extremely fragile because if you can't get exactly that 192.168.8.0/24 network it won't work, so I can't run this test locally on my desktop, on non-Docker VMs, ....

This should get you to a situation where you don't care about these IP addresses at all.  You do need to modify your test service to understand the environment variable.  But otherwise a `docker-compose.yml` file that's equivalent to what you show would be

```
version: "3"
services:
  service-1:
    build: <service_path>
  test-executor-1:
    build: <test_scripts_path>
    environment:
      SERVICE_URL: 'http://service-1/'
```

(The most obvious mechanical problem is that from a Linux host or VM, you can directly reach the Docker-internal IP addresses, so if multiple containers want to have the same address, it's not obvious which container 192.168.8.1 would be.  You can also connect containers to multiple networks and they'd get an IP address in each network, which prevents networks from sharing an address range.)